# Remove tag <center> effect

Tags: asp.net, html, center

How can I remove the `<center>` tag?

I set `<center>` all ContentPlaceHolder in MasterPage, so all the body aspx pages are center for default. 
How can I remove/anullate that effect without removing `<center>` tag in masterPage?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS instead of <center>? A div with width:500px and margin:auto should be centered inside its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  tag is not supported in HTML5, and is being depreciated. You should look for another solution to your problem.

Instead of the center tag you could use a div tag with a class that has the attribute 'Text-align:center'. Then in the children tags state 'Text-align:Left' or similar.

Comment: Thanks! Text-align:Left in body page results! I didn't know <center> is out of usage!

Answer (score 0):

```
center {
float: left; }
```

Simply adjust to your needs (as mentioned in other answers, like margin: auto).

Best way to do is to declare this in a custom CSS (assuming you are talking about SharePoint 2007/2010).

Comment: As mentiod, adjust it to your needs. float: left was simply an exmaple that it is possibly to clear the effect of the <center>-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a nice example of why the `center` tag is deprecated and shouldn't be used at all. HTML shouldn't be dictating the way something looks.

If you don't care for standard compliance, you can add a style to your `center` tag to make it float left. I'd recommend replacing it with an accordingly styled  `div` though.